# Django: Allowing only one booleanfield to be True

Tags: python, django

Having a such model, I want to make sure only one Photo for each album to have a cover. This will be used as InlineModelAdmin to the Album model.

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    is_cover = models.BooleanField( default=False)
    album = models.ForeignKey('Album')
    image = ImageField(upload_to='uploads')
```

How can this be achieved ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Which photo is on the cover of the album should be **a property of the album, not the Photo.**

Instead of using a boolean property in your Photos, use a reference to a Photo in your Album.

**Answer to Comment:** Assuming that 'inline model' means what I assume it to be in my comment, you will probably have to provide your own [add form template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.add_form_template). Using it, you can still provide the option boxes  (instead of check boxes) and then set up the `Album` correctly in the code that processes the contents of the submitted form.

Comment: but this way how can I allow user to select the cover photo at the initial instance creation ? photos are inline models of album.

Comment: @Hellnar: I am not sure if I understand the term "inline model" correctly (I never used django). Do you mean that when you create a album on a admin page that the same page also allows you to add photos to the album?

Comment: Exactly and at that condition this is a problem